# I have a request to add another Q & A site for popular open source e-commerce systems

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wondering about adding another Q & A wiki for various popular e-commerce systems such as Magento and ZenCart.

This will help provide a forum for those who are not as familiar with the systems and are trying to jump start an online store.

I am sure this could be a popular one as there are many e-commerce systems out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you are looking for is [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  It's where you can make proposals for new sites to be added to the StackExchange network.  From the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for that site, it's the place where people can:

> - Propose new Q&A sites. If you have an idea for an expert Q&A site, propose it here.
> - Get involved in the process. Help sites get off the ground by defining the types of questions that are wanted, recruiting a critical
>     mass of experts, and committing to the site's success.

Comment: Thank you if this could be moved over there that would be great. I did not know that Area 51 site existed.

Comment: I don't think migration is possible.  You'll have to go over to Area51 and submit the proposal separately [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology) (they are a little different than just asking questions).  As @JeremyBanks mentioned in his answer, there is already one for [Magento](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento) - so you may just want to support it.  Glad I could help out =)

Answer (score 0):

New sites are proposed, voted on and discussed at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) <sup>[[announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/)], [[faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)]</sup>. There isn't an existing proposal for exactly what you've described, but there is [one for Magento Q&A](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento). It's waiting for enough interested people to "follow" it.